# cms Enveloped Data binary encoding problem in pkijs

Tags: javascript, encryption, pki, asn.1, ber

I'm trying trying to implement exchange of CMS encrypted content using the pkijs library.
Basically I've just copied the example from here: https://pkijs.org/examples/CMSEnvelopedExample.html

here the excerpt for encryption

```
cmsEnveloped.addRecipientByCertificate(certSimpl, {  oaepHashAlgorithm: oaepHashAlg });

return cmsEnveloped.encrypt(encAlg, valueBuffer).then(() => {
  var cmsContentSimpl = new ContentInfo();
  cmsContentSimpl.contentType = "1.2.840.113549.1.7.3";
  cmsContentSimpl.content = cmsEnveloped.toSchema();
  cmsEnvelopedBuffer = cmsContentSimpl.toSchema().toBER(false);
```

The problematic part is the binary encoding of the asn.1 schema with `.toBER(false)`.
If the valueBuffer is not extremely small it is very slow ~13sek for 1 Mb.
My question are: why is this so slow? and could I just encode it differently e.g. `toJSON()`and then `stringToArrayBuffer`? Are there any security concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some unoptimized code in the implementation of `toBER` in `asn1js`. You should upgrade the dependency to `asn1js@2.4.0` if you encounter the same problem. This is the issue on github: https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/PKI.js/issues/347